# Android ListView: change item view one by one

Tags: android, listview, loops, rows

I have a ListView which is built using a BaseAdapter with a custom item layout. I would like to implement a button where, when clicked, the list item views are highlighted one by one with a delay.

So when the button is clicked the first row is highlighted (can be achieved through changing the views background etc), then after 4 seconds the second row is highlight, with the previous row unhighlighted until the loop is broken or the end of the list is reached.

I have been searching a lot for a solution and while iterating the items I have found this may cause performance issues. This is what I have so far, which I have found effects all child views with the same ID (I am guessing as it's re-using the view in getView):

```
int start = 0;

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    int childCount = lv.getChildCount();
    TextView tv;

    for (int i = start; i < childCount; i++) {
        View v = lv.getChildAt(i);
        tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.wordListEngLabel);
        tv.setText("here");
    }
```

Comment: you are initializing textview evertime in your for loop which is not required `TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.wordListEngLabel)`. move it outside the for loop

Comment: Ok thanks, I've changed this... how can I delay the change to every 4 seconds and effect all views, not just the visible ones?

Comment: use a timer or a handler

Comment: I have tried a handler and a timer but have found all views are changed at once, once the handler or timer has finished? - do you have any sample code?